# Can anyone please interpret this sentence on employment?

Tags: unemployment

**If the increase in labour force has been higher than the rate of population growth, it means that the population is becoming younger requiring the creation of new job opportunities at an increasing rate**

A little example to elucidate this statement might also help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way: it’s 1968, the first of the baby boomers are turning ~20. The population growth rate has slowed from its post-WWII peak, but nearly all the baby boomers are now looking for a job. The population growth rate is now lower than the labor force growth rate. Second, the massive number of young people is bringing the average age down as the lost generation, 1900s, begins to die.